# C# OrderBy DateTime? without empty values taking priority

Tags: c#, linq

Currently I have the following LINQ extension to order my list by ascending order

`var reportsAscending  = report.OrderBy(x => x.ApprovalAuditDate).ToList();`

But the problem I am having is that the list named `reportsAscending` has empty Approval Audit Dates at the start of the list rather than dates.

[image]

Is there a way to get the empty/null dates towards the end of the list?

The property is `public DateTime? ApprovalAuditDate { get; set; }`

For data type `string` I am using `report.OrderBy(x => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.ApprovalStatus)).ThenBy(x => x.ApprovalStatus).ToList();` which works perfectly

Comment: See duplicate. `.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date.HasValue).ThenBy(x => x.Date)`.

Comment: `report.OrderBy(x => x.ApprovalAuditDate ?? DateTime.MaxValue)`

Comment: Thank you very much +1 for converting it into Lambda

Comment: The expression from @Fabio worked